# Wrong output in diff command

Tags: linux, unix, diff

I use diff to compare the following files and get the wrong answer. Here are my files.

File 1:

```
0
350
853
903
1414
1724
2201
2979
3883
4195
```

File 2:

```
0
350
853
903
1414
1724
2201
2979
3883
4195
```

And here is the result:

```
1,10c1,10
< 0
< 350
< 853
< 903
< 1414
< 1724
< 2201
< 2979
< 3883
< 4195
---
> 0
> 350
> 853
> 903
> 1414
> 1724
> 2201
> 2979
> 3883
> 4195
```

Actually, these are parts of two long files that were the output of my programming assignments. I use diff to check the my answer. But it return a bazzle result. How can this happen?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no differences in the line format or non visible characters (spaces)?

Comment: Following the suggestion of @Matteo, try `diff -w` or `-iwB` or see the man page for more options.

Comment: When using diff -w, there is no difference.

Comment: @terencehill Thank you. I got it.